# System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2016 Storage Status Reserved

Tags: system-center, storage-spaces

We are in the process of setting up a storage spaces direct cluster. We have provisioned 3 cluster disks that are visible and working from each cluster node.

we have added the disks to the cluster in SCVMM, but VM's will not provision onto it.

having investigated further, under each host -> properties -> storage -> select disk.. the status says Reserved. For the local storage, it says Online.

Anyone know what this means, and if it is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

seems it is not related to the issue i was facing, i had neglected to mark the vm i was creating as highly available.

Comment: If you have resolved the issue by yourself, please mark your reply as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I too fell into this trap. Only by enabling the "Make this virtual machine highly available" enables the VM to be stored on a CSV shared volume

[image: 1]